# Do eye doctors check for tunnel vision?

Tags: optometry, opthalmology, tunnel-vision, eye-exam

Whenever I go in for an eye exam, I am subjected to [Snellen charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snellen_chart) (where the letters only appear in the center of my field of vision), air puffs against my eyes, and a bright light shined into my eyes for a few minutes.  The periphery of my field of vision is never tested.  Why is that?

The reason I ask is because I believe my father has had tunnel vision for years now.  Whenever I walk directly in front of him, he sees me, but if I approach him from an angle, then won't notice me (unless I make a noise).  My mother says when he's driving, he gets honked at frequently when changing lanes, because she thinks his field of vision is so poor that he can't see the cars in the other lanes.  This is a safety concern.

My father did get an eye exam one or two years ago, and apparently they said his vision was fine.  If that's the case, then I highly doubt they checked his peripheral vision.